# Make React-Select with multi select work on small screens (no vertical expand)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to make the React-Select component work on small screens. For this I would like the component not to expand vertically. If there is enough space within the component I would like to see the following if two options have been selected:

```
Option1 (2) //Option1 and Option2 selected
```

If there is not enough space the following is desired:

```
Opt... (2) //Option1 and Option2 selected
```

Or at least

```
Opt... //Option1 and Option2 selected, counter not visible anymmore
```

For this I combined two examples:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v638kx67w7
https://codesandbox.io/s/xv2ql44xxp

However it has a strange bug that I could not fix. If you select the first name, then click outside the component, then add second name, click outside the component, then click to add another option, it happens that the contents of the component is somehow shifted to the left and the first character(s) disappear.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-9v3fr (make sure to reduce the width of the column containing the component so that it is narrower than the first entry)

This is how the cropped component contents looks like:

[image: Component contents cropped on the left]

I tried to change several CSS properties in the browser dev tools, but couldn't find out what causes the behaviour. Any hints or even a solution?

Comment: In your code, it display only the first selected name, whatever I select.
If I select 3 names, there's written "Georg Weidlinger (3)" for me.

Comment: That is intended, the parenthesis contain a counter of the selected items. You will always see the name of the first selected item.

Comment: oh okay. I can't reproduce the bug though, when doing what you described. Tried in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Interesting, I cannot reproduce the bug on Chrome. However on Firefox 74 on MacOS I can observe it every time I follow the click procedure as provided.